# MSChart for C# on Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows-7, mschart, visual-studio-2012, visual-c#-express-2010

I started developing an app on Windows XP and VIsual C# Express 2010. This app uses MSChart components. Now I need to get this app ready for Winodws 7. Therefore I installed Win 7 and Visual C# Express 2010 (and also Visula Studio 11 Beta) but I can't get the MSChart to work. It's not listed in the tools windows and I can't selectet it with "Choose items...". I downloaded and installed the Microsoft Chart Controls für Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 (MSCHART.exe) but i can't get it working neither in V C# Express 2010 nor in VS11B.

Does MSChart no long work on new systems or am I doing something wrong? I'm thankfull for any help!

edit: just figured out that on both Visual C# Express 2010 and Visual Studio 11 Beta a .net 4 project will show MSChart tool in tools window. changing to .net 3.5 will remove the chart tool in both environments...

Problem is: the app needs to work on XP with .net 3.5 (not higher) and Win 7.

Comment: Do you have the appropriate assembly references?

Answer (score 0):

Is your version of Window7, Office or you app 64bit, we have had a number of issues with running Active X and OCX on 64bit Platform.

Comment: Indeed, I'm running Win7 64bit. Currently don't have any Office installed (but I was to install a 64 bit Version). But machines where the final app should run are 32bit version. (as you can see in my question-edit: mschart runs with .net 4 but not with .net 3.5)